# How do i make a Php script terminate after a fixed amout of time

Tags: php

How do i make a Php script terminate after a fixed amount of time

Answer (score 4):

Using the max_execution_time setting in PHP.

Ie:

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', 30);
```

Would end the script after 30 seconds of execution (this is default in PHP)

You could also use:

```
set_time_limit(30);
```

See: http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php and http://www.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-execution-time

Answer (score 1):

I would use the `set_time_limit()` function which specifies the amount of time a script is allowed to run after the point at which this function has been called.

More info [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php)